# how to call child anchor click on parent div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have multiple instances of

```
<div class="picOuterDiv">
   <a href="examplepage.php?var=1" class="iframe" > page one </a>
</div>

<div class="picOuterDiv">
   <a href="examplepage.php?var=2" class="iframe" > page two </a>
</div>
```

Now I am using jQuery colorbox plugin to create Lightbox's. The lightBox opens when i click the anchor element, The anchor element with the class iframe. It works fine till here, using

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"646", height:"675"});
```

What I want is to open the colorbox when I click the parent div. I used the following code to trigger anchor element href when div was clicked, but apparently the href alone wasnt enough, the element clicked should have the class "iframe" . So its not working with this code.

```
$('.picOuterDiv').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        });
});
```

So can anybody help me on how I can make this work ? I hope the Problem is clear. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/VhkFN/3/

Comment: the answer below or just make your anchor fill the whole div using CSS.

Comment: @popnoodles can you see the js fiddle ? i have edited the question

Comment: See Christophe's answer, it's the only correct one despite the +1s. And he also mentioned the var arr[] which I see was still in your code. http://jsfiddle.net/VhkFN/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what worked for me. As i said i was using jquery colorbox.

```
$(".picOuterDiv").click(function () {
   var anchorHref = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
   $(this).colorbox ({iframe:true, width:"646", height:"675", href: anchorHref});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.picOuterDiv').click(function() {
   window.location.href=$(this).find('a').attr('href');
});​
```

There are a couple issues with your fiddle. First "var arr[]" is not correct. Second, the hyperlink doesn't have any [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) property, so triggering a click won't do much. You need to grab its href attribute instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VhkFN/4/

Comment: what, a hyperlink doesn't have any onclick behaviour? what do you suppose it does?

Comment: @popnoodles I have added a reference in my answer, and changed "behavior" to "property" for clarity. We are talking about JavaScript here, not html. Try the other answers to understand what I mean.

Comment: hmmm.. let me think about this. actually i'm going to try it... Yes everyone except you was wrong it seems. In fact triggering the click on the child bubbles back back up which then triggers the click... Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: that was my original method @christophe . But the problem with that code is it does follow the link. but does not open a colorbox pop. As I mentioned I am using jQuery colorbox plugin.

Comment: @jinni ok, but your original code to get href was not correct. I see that you have now fixed it in your final code.

Comment: preventing multiple clicks `jQuery(".picOuterDiv").has('a').one('click', function (e) {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").first().attr("href");
  })`